# Spring loaded hibernate connection in ireport

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, ireport

I have a Spring Web MVC project. And, I am trying to Create a Spring Loaded Hibernate Connection in IReport using the existing spring web mvc projects application context.

In IReport, In the Options window, in the ClassPath tab, I have added all the latest Spring jars used by the project. As well as the application context's folder.

But, I am getting the following error while testing the connection

> Error Creating bean name 'mySessionFactory' defined in the class path resource spring-hibernate.xml: invocation of init method failed;nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found.

Has anyone successfully connected using the Spring loaded Hibernate connection in Ireport?

Answer (score 2):

IReport uses internally an outdated Version of Spring(I think it is 2.0.0) so if you have for example Annotated Spring and Hibernate, there is no Chance to get run, because Ireport has a heavy use of Reflections.

So if you try to us a CustomClassLoader, you will hit a wall, because IReport tries to load your also after you give it your Custom DataSource.